# Which ratio of INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT recommends using an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I know that indexing helps to select queries but also hinders the insert and update ones as the engine as to do it in the original table and in the indexes...

So if you mainly do insert/updates statements maybe it's more recommended to do not create indexes and vice versa. Despite it depends on which queries you need to run faster.

In my case I need first to select and after that insert, with the same importance. So this is a 50/50 scenario. Should I create indexes then?

Comment: Don't forget that also UPDATE may use indexes to perform faster. (Both SELECT and UPDATE have the same WHERE clause...)

Comment: you're totally right, but its not the case. I was referring that the update would have to modify the indexes tables too. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: And if an INSERT takes 0.1 seconds without indexes, and 0.2 seconds with index, and an important select takes 0.5 seconds with index, and 10 hours without index?

Comment: "I need to select and after that insert" implies you may be doing something silly, like checking if the data is already in the database before adding it.

Comment: mmm In fact I need to check if the las inset with certain conditions happened X minutes ago. If not, then I insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have selects,updates then index will definitely, but if you have more inserts then index creation and updation is an overhead which will slow you down in terms of performance. General ratio could be 80-90% (select + updates) and 10% or less inserts so that tradeoff should look beneficial.

If you have data loading in bulk (less frequent) then import utility can help you and during that activity you can safely drop index and after inserting data rebuild the index again.

Comment: Si in my case 50/50 is better to avoid the use of indexes?

Comment: As I said, Indexes will help you in select + updates but will hunt you for insert. If you are okay with that slowness (find out how much time it will take for insert,read,update with and without index) If you need advantage for read then you should add index. If you need inserts fast then either drop index or try lazy inserts (import utility) with customized code.